# Subsonic 2.2 - Update with expresssion - how to make my solution better?

Tags: subsonic, expression

I'm learning SubSonic 2.2, and have the following query, but it feels "Wrong" writing my expression ("count + 1") as a string.

Can any experts suggest a better way that this?

```
            int records = new Update(Wordsfile.Schema)
            .SetExpression(Wordsfile.CountColumn).EqualTo("count + 1")
            .Where(Wordsfile.Columns.WordId).IsEqualTo(wordID)
            .And(Wordsfile.Columns.FileId).IsEqualTo(fileID)
            .Execute();
```

It's the line:  ".SetExpression(Wordsfile.CountColumn).EqualTo("count + 1")".

I've tried: ".SetExpression(Wordsfile.CountColumn).EqualTo(Wordsfile.Columns.Count + 1)", but no joy.

Any suggestions

Thanks!

Comment: I would fetch the matching Wordsfile object and handle it in a typed way. Something like file.Count++; file.Save();

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead:

```
.SetExpression(Wordsfile.CountColumn).EqualTo(Wordsfile.Columns.Count + " + 1")
```

Comment: Great stuff!

That's certainly in improvment, but can anyone think of a way of achieving this without the use of strings?

I guess it could also be done with a sub-query, but that seems a bit messy, when using straight sql, the additional query wouldnt be needed.

Answer (score 1):

Strings aren't so bad and in your case it's pretty simple stuff ("+1"). You could throw a trigger in there :) if you wanted...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 .SetExpression("count").EqualTo("count + 1")
```

Because in update.cs,the code is:

```
public Setting SetExpression(TableSchema.TableColumn col)

return CreateSetting(col.ColumnName, col.DataType, true);
```